# Moodle - Front page ->Login

Tags: moodle

How do I remove access to Moodle's front page for unauthenticated users?

I want the users to land on the login page first, even if they go to the base url.

I've set the following setting to 'Yes'

```
Prevent account creation when authenticating
authpreventaccountcreation
```

So users, if they're going directly to a course, or other resource are prompted for login first, but if they simply go to eg 'mymoodle.com' they are presented with the front page, and have to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to site admin -> security -> site policies

or direct to /admin/settings.php?section=sitepolicies

and ensure 'force users to login' is checked.